# Error while compiling a C++ application on a raspberry pi

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, raspberry-pi, gcc4

I would like to ask where does this error come from:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/issues> for instructions.
CMakeFiles/supnsa_parser.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/supnsa_parser.dir/src/helper.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/supnsa_parser.dir/src/helper.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/supnsa_parser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/supnsa_parser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm getting this on my raspberry pi when I launch the compilation of my C++ application.
Where does it come from? How can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: This is a bug in the compiler. You solve it by becoming a compiler developer, getting assigned the relevant ticket, and merging a fix. Failing that, submit a bug report as suggested in the error message, and wait until somebody else merges a fix. Meanwhile you may try rewriting the offending file such that the same functionality is implemented in a different way, in order to avoid triggering the bug.

Comment: Type `gcc --version` and try to switch to a newer version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do internal compiler error messages mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405606/what-do-internal-compiler-error-messages-mean)

Comment: I am facing same issue. Do you got any solution to this?

Comment: I had the same issue just bumped up the RAM and CPU and its now working perfectly. Its being forcefully shutdown by the operating system as its trying to use all the resources it has, so it gets terminated. this is a developers bug the software should never require that much memory to perform a task.

Answer (score 4):

Usually `Killed` message during compilation indicates *out of memory* issue as most of the compilation processes requires higher amount of memory, so you should either increase it (if you can, check with `free -m` or `top` command), or another solution is to [create a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/a/796997/78223) and re-run compilation again.

See also: [Out Of Memory Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) in Linux Kernel.