# I got this error on CodeBlocks, but if I fix it, it has an error that is triggered FROM fixing the first one. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, gnu

I keep getting an error in Code::Blocks after compiling:

```
 '''
    error: expected ';' after class definition
 '''
```

, but when I add the semicolon in, it gives me:

```
    internal compiler error: in gt_pch_note_object, at 
    ggc-common.c:276
    };
```

specifying the semicolon I had just added in behind the curly bracket. Either way, there is still an error. What is wrong with it??
The class I was writing was:

```
class Game{
     public:
     Game();
     ~Game();
     void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int 
     width, int height, bool fullscreen);
     void handleEvents();
     void update();
     void render();
     void clean();
     bool running();
     private:
     bool isRunning;
     SDL_Window *window;
     SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};
```

I was using the SDL2 library to write a game. Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Given the little code you posted, what is a `SDL_Window` or `SDL_Renderer`?  If I were the compiler and that is all you gave to me compile, those are the errors that would come up.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Given that your error is `internal compiler error` what made you think that code was responsible? Please post the smallest **complete** code that causes this error.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with the posted code.  You are not defining the types `SDL_Window` and `SDL_Renderer`.  There are no `#include` statements.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That code is taken out of context, that's obvious. And even if it were not it should not be causing an internal compiler error.

Comment: Technically, the error was basically pointing out the end of the class definition, specifically 
     '};'  (If I'm correct, I pointed out that the code I was showing was the class. Before that, I had '#include <iostream>' and '#include <SDL2/SDL.h>'). I don't know about the whole "out of context" thing, that might be true.

Answer (score 0):

internal compiler errors are usually tricky and they are bugs within the compiler itself even though your code is fine.

I would suggest trying a different compiler, maybe a more recent version.

See: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405606/what-do-internal-compiler-error-messages-mean-and-what-can-i-do)

Comment: I'm not experienced with CodeBlocks but I never seen an internal compiler error in Visual Studio that wasn't caused by a problem in my code, and wasn't fixed by fixing my code.